How can I remove the extra space between the Text and DynamicHeightGridView in my Flutter app?
I am working on a Flutter app, and I have a page where I display some product details. The layout works fine, but there is unwanted extra space between the Text widget and DynamicHeightGridView on mobile screens.
Here's the relevant code:
const SizedBox(height: 10),
const Text(
  'Suggested products', // <<<---------- Here
  style: TextStyle(fontWeight: FontWeight.w500, fontSize: 20),
),
DynamicHeightGridView(
  crossAxisSpacing: 10,
  physics: const NeverScrollableScrollPhysics(),
  shrinkWrap: true,
  builder: (ctx, index) => const ProductComponent(),
  itemCount: 3,
  crossAxisCount: 2,
),

image of layout
What I've

Adjusted the padding and margin values of the Column and Padding widgets.
Set the shrinkWrap: true and NeverScrollableScrollPhysics() for DynamicHeightGridView.

However, the issue still persists. Any suggestions on how to fix this extra space issue?
Screenshot
image with border
This is Full code

import 'package:carousel_slider_plus/carousel_slider_plus.dart';
import 'package:dynamic_height_grid_view/dynamic_height_grid_view.dart';
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:spiskauz/components/product_component.dart';
import 'package:spiskauz/theme.dart';

class ProductDetailPage extends StatefulWidget {
  const ProductDetailPage({super.key});

  @override
  State<ProductDetailPage> createState() => _ProductDetailPageState();
}

class _ProductDetailPageState extends State<ProductDetailPage> {
  int activeIndex = 0;

  List<String> images = [
    'assets/images/image.png',
    'assets/images/image.png',
    'assets/images/image.png',
  ];

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      body: SingleChildScrollView(
        child: Column(
          crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.start,
          children: [
            Stack(
              children: [
                Ink(
                  padding: EdgeInsets.only(top: MediaQuery.paddingOf(context).top, bottom: 20),
                  width: double.maxFinite,
                  decoration: BoxDecoration(color: Colors.grey.shade200),
                  child: Column(
                    children: [
                      CarouselSlider(
                        options: CarouselOptions(
                          height: 400,
                          autoPlay: true,
                          enlargeCenterPage: true,
                          aspectRatio: 16 / 9,
                          viewportFraction: 0.9,
                          onPageChanged: (index, reason) => setState(() => activeIndex = index),
                        ),
                        items: images.map(
                          (image) {
                            return Center(
                              child: Image.asset(
                                image,
                                fit: BoxFit.cover,
                              ),
                            );
                          },
                        ).toList(),
                      ),
                      const SizedBox(height: 20),
                      Row(
                        mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.center,
                        mainAxisSize: MainAxisSize.max,
                        children: images.asMap().entries.map((entry) {
                          return GestureDetector(
                            onTap: () => setState(() => activeIndex = entry.key),
                            child: Container(
                              width: 10,
                              height: 10,
                              margin: const EdgeInsets.symmetric(horizontal: 4),
                              decoration: BoxDecoration(
                                shape: BoxShape.circle,
                                color: activeIndex == entry.key ? Colors.black : Colors.white,
                              ),
                            ),
                          );
                        }).toList(),
                      ),
                    ],
                  ),
                ),
                Positioned(
                  top: 45,
                  left: 10,
                  child: IconButton(onPressed: () => Navigator.pop(context), icon: const Icon(Icons.arrow_back)),
                ),
                Positioned(
                  top: 45,
                  right: 10,
                  child: Container(
                    padding: const EdgeInsets.symmetric(horizontal: 10, vertical: 2),
                    decoration: BoxDecoration(
                      borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(12),
                      color: Colors.red,
                    ),
                    child: const Text(
                      '-10%',
                      style: TextStyle(color: Colors.white),
                    ),
                  ),
                ),
              ],
            ),
            Padding(
              padding: const EdgeInsets.symmetric(horizontal: 16, vertical: 30),
              child: Column(
                crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.start,
                children: [
                  const Text(
                    'Qorem ipsum dolor sit amet',
                    style: TextStyle(
                      fontWeight: FontWeight.w500,
                      fontSize: 20,
                      letterSpacing: -1,
                    ),
                  ),
                  const SizedBox(height: 10),
                  const Text('Narxi', style: TextStyle(color: Colors.black45)),
                  const SizedBox(height: 5),
                  const Text(
                    '3 500 000 so’m',
                    style: TextStyle(
                      color: Colors.red,
                      fontSize: 16,
                      decoration: TextDecoration.lineThrough,
                      decorationColor: Colors.red,
                    ),
                  ),
                  const Text(
                    '2 999 999 so’m',
                    style: TextStyle(
                      fontSize: 24,
                      fontWeight: FontWeight.w700,
                      letterSpacing: -1,
                    ),
                  ),
                  const SizedBox(height: 10),
                  const Text('Maxsulot tafsifi', style: TextStyle(fontWeight: FontWeight.w500, fontSize: 16)),
                  const SizedBox(height: 3),
                  const Text('Norem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Nunc vulputate libero et velit interdum, ac aliquet odio mattis norem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Nunc vulputate libero et velit interdum, ac aliquet odio mattis', overflow: TextOverflow.ellipsis, softWrap: true, maxLines: 2, style: TextStyle(fontSize: 16)),
                  InkWell(
                    onTap: () {},
                    child: const Row(
                      mainAxisSize: MainAxisSize.min,
                      children: [
                        Text(
                          'Batafsil',
                          style: TextStyle(fontWeight: FontWeight.w500, fontSize: 16),
                        ),
                        SizedBox(width: 5),
                        Icon(Icons.keyboard_arrow_down_rounded),
                      ],
                    ),
                  ),
                  const SizedBox(height: 10),
                  const Text(
                    'Sotuvda 100 dona bor',
                    style: TextStyle(
                      color: Colors.green,
                      fontWeight: FontWeight.w500,
                      fontSize: 16,
                    ),
                  ),
                  const SizedBox(height: 10),
                  Row(
                    children: [
                      Expanded(
                        child: TextField(
                          decoration: InputDecoration(
                            border: OutlineInputBorder(borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(10)),
                            contentPadding: const EdgeInsets.all(10),
                            // isDense: true,
                            isCollapsed: true,
                            labelText: 'Bo\'yi',
                          ),
                        ),
                      ),
                      const SizedBox(width: 15),
                      Expanded(
                        child: TextField(
                          decoration: InputDecoration(
                            border: OutlineInputBorder(borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(10)),
                            contentPadding: const EdgeInsets.all(10),
                            // isDense: true,
                            isCollapsed: true,
                            labelText: 'Eni',
                          ),
                        ),
                      ),
                    ],
                  ),
                  const SizedBox(height: 10),
                  Row(
                    children: [
                      const Expanded(
                        child: Column(
                          crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.start,
                          children: [
                            Text('Narxi'),
                            Text(
                              '2 999 999 so’m',
                              style: TextStyle(fontSize: 20, fontWeight: FontWeight.w700, letterSpacing: -1),
                            ),
                          ],
                        ),
                      ),
                      const SizedBox(width: 15),
                      Expanded(
                        child: Ink(
                          padding: const EdgeInsets.symmetric(vertical: 12),
                          decoration: BoxDecoration(
                            borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(16),
                            color: AppColors.secondaryColor,
                          ),
                          child: const Row(
                            mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.center,
                            children: [
                              Icon(Icons.shopping_cart),
                              SizedBox(width: 10),
                              Text('Savatga'),
                            ],
                          ),
                        ),
                      ),
                    ],
                  ),
                  const SizedBox(height: 10),
                  const Text(
                    'O\'xshash mahsulotlar',
                    style: TextStyle(fontWeight: FontWeight.w500, fontSize: 20),
                  ),
                  DynamicHeightGridView(
                    crossAxisSpacing: 10,
                    physics: const NeverScrollableScrollPhysics(),
                    shrinkWrap: true,
                    builder: (ctx, index) => const ProductComponent(),
                    itemCount: 3,
                    crossAxisCount: 2,
                  ),
                ],
              ),
            ),
          ],
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
}




You want to remove the space between Suggested products and DynamicHeightGridView list?

can u draw a border around the DynamicHeightGridView  and share the image? and also can u add padding and make the padding values 0.

Rakesh i got  it

can u please update the code too?

Rakesh there isn't padding or margin

i used DevTools

can u provide a simple reproducible sample code

I updated the code

what is DynamicHeightGridView?

package on pub.dev
https://pub.dev/packages/dynamic_height_grid_view

as i try to code text  and  DynamicHeightGridView it look fine can you provide ProductComponent code
